# Candle Wick | Shadow doesn't trigger close limit

Tags: pine-script

Can someone explain me how I can close a trade, when the candle shadow|wick cross the price. Here you can see that shadow|wick is well above the green line (band), which is the targeted price :

[image: Wick well above the targeted price]

Thanks in advance for your expertise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can refer to the wick with either `high` or `low`.

In your case, you want to do:

```
wick_high_cross = ta.crossover(high, green_line_price)

if (wick_high_cross)
    strategy.close()
```